# Change of Junit Report Format

Tags: testing, report, junit5

My JUnit report is generated in a way that all the test in the class forms the Total Test Cases. I want that the report should conatin the Total test cases as per the different mehtods. Eg. My class conatins 3 tests and currently when the report is geenarted it shows total as 16. However , I want individual test method report.
Test1 has 10 cases, so it should be 10 paased and 0 failed
Test2 has 4 cases, it should be 2 passed and 2 failed
Test3 has 2 cases, it should be 2 passed 0 failed.